# CalendarView minimum date

Tags: android, calendarview

I created a CalendarView and I don't want to show previous months.

I tried this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int date = calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE);

CalendarView calendar_view = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
calendar_view.setMinDate(date);
```

Nothing seems to happen. The calendar works as normal.

Answer (score 4):

Try calculating the date like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE));
long date = calendar.getTime().getTime();
```

and set this as minimum date:

```
calendar_view.setMinDate(date);
```

since calendar_view.setMinDate(date) needs long value that represents milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

```
calendar_view.setMinDate((new Date().getTime()));
```

works just fine

Answer (score -1):

You can just set the min date as below.

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 CalendarView cv = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
 cv.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: where is the minimum date? this is actually the current date

Comment: what does mean where is minimum date? you are setting min date to of calendarview to current date, and it will not show previous months.