# Android CalendarView: cannot set min date and selected date

Tags: android, date

I know the Android `CalendarView` is among the buggiest piece of software in human history, but I must use it so came here asking.

I need to open a `CalendarView` with:

- minimum date set to today;
- selected date set to today.

This is how I do it:

```
int day = 8;
int month = 2;
int year = 2015;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, day);

CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
calendarView.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis()-2000);

calendarView.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), true, false);
fixIncredibleBugOfCalendarView(calendarView, calendar);
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
```

When I run the previous code, the `CalendarView`:

- shows the 9th of March as the first selectable day, instead of the 8th (`DAY_OF_MONTH` starts from 1);
- shows the 15th of March as the selected date;

So I have geniously decided to include the two lines marked with *:

```
int day = 8;
int month = 2;
int year = 2015;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(year, month, day);

CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1); // * - subtract one day, i.e. March 7
calendarView.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); // * add one day, back to 8
calendarView.setDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), true, false);
fixIncredibleBugOfCalendarView(calendarView, calendar);
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
```

In the first line I remove one day, in the second I add one.

With these two more lines, my `CalendarView` shows:

- the 7th of March, as the first selectable date;
- the 15th of March, as the selected date.

The method `fixIncredibleBugOfCalendarView(...)` should fix something (I found it on SO):

```
private void fixIncredibleBugOfCalendarView(CalendarView cal, Calendar date) {
        // Workaround for CalendarView bug relating to setMinDate():
        // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42750
        // Set then reset the date on the calendar so that it properly
        // shows today's date. The choice of 24 months is arbitrary.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            date.add(Calendar.MONTH, 24);
            cal.setDate(date.getTimeInMillis(), false, true);
            date.add(Calendar.MONTH, -24);
            cal.setDate(date.getTimeInMillis(), false, true);
        }
    }
```

This should not be so hard and I do not think it's a bug: it is more likely that it's my fault. Two questions: Could you please be so kind to tell me how to:

- tell `CalendarView` the minimum date it should display?
- have `CalendarView` showing as `selected` what I decide is the selected date?

Cheers

Comment: If CalendarView is buggy, why not use [an alternative](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) ? There are also some other alternatives.

Comment: Thank you. Since I spent an afternoon on this, I would like to see if someone is able to solve the problem: it is a very simple task. Otherwise I will use alternatives (it is hard to believe that a simple chooser made by Android devs is so buggy, while alternatives are not).

Comment: Maybe try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20683328/4428462), possibly together with your `fixIncredibleBugOfCalendarView` method ?

Answer (score 0):

This is  late, probably you have already solved the thing . But Here is my code to solve it

```
   android.icu.util.Calendar c = android.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    Long min = c.getTime().getTime();
    Long max = 2629746000L + c.getTime().getTime();


    CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
    cv.setMinDate(min);
    cv.setMaxDate(max);
```

You can also CalenderView just needs to have mindate in long format. You can also go for java

```
Data d = new Date();
d.getTime();
```

But Somehow it doesnt work because of current TimeZone. 
Instead Calender returns a dateObject with respect to Current TimeZone set.